# Ligntning datatables actions menu hidden

Tags: datatable

On Lightning Datatables the actions menus is hidden when the table has few rows (1-3 rows). See attached screenshot for more info.

Any workaround till its fixed is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This post does not contain a question.

Comment: Apologies. The question is how do I fix the action menu overflow hidden issue (red circle in the screenshot) via CSS.

Comment: did you resolve your issue, i too had similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS.

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable_x
{overflow-y:visible!important;overflow-x:visible!important;}
.THIS .slds-scrollable_y
{overflow-y:visible!important;overflow-x:visible!important;}
```