# Action Menu Getting Partially Cut Off

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

[image]

As seen in the two images above, I have an LWC DataTable with row actions that are being partially cut off (both upward and downward).  I have tried the following:

[Ligntning datatables actions menu hidden](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209086/ligntning-datatables-actions-menu-hidden/215348)

And the 5 other identical (Stack and SuccessSF) posts that say the same thing, but nothing changes the behavior.  My grid lives inside of a **Modal**, with one other grid (if that makes a difference).  How do I make the row actions show up on top of the grid, instead of underneith the columns and only within the boundaries of the grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue with the `lightning-datatable` action column and found that setting the `menuAlignment` to `auto` fixed it for me.
So, try that inside where you are declaring your column for the actions.

```
{
  type: 'action', 
  typeAttributes: {
    rowActions: [{...}],
    menuAlignment: 'auto'
  }
}
```

Comment: You are the man!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I know it frustrated me.